# Bind HTML from Json attribute to table

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

Is it possible to pass an HTML string in a JSON structure to a table and then view the string as HTML in the table cell?

I am using ng-material-treetable in Angular and wondering if the object passed into ng-material-treetable can contain html and display that html instead of just text.

EG:

```
json = {
 columnName: '<p style="bold">cell data</p>'
}
```

From that object the table column name would be columnName and the cell should show 'cell data' in bold, it is obviously showing

`<p style="bold">cell data</p>` but wondering if something like this is possible?

```
|columnName|                                         |columnName|
------------                         ----->          ------------
|<p style="bold">cell data</p>|                      |cell data| <- this text would be bold
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use innerHTML it will show **cell data** instead so I guess you use innerText or textContent?

Comment: @mplungjan - The table is built from the json object so not using something like that. 
Actually using ng-material-treetable where the table gets built from the json structure.

Comment: You cannot do `<th [innerHtml]={{columnName}}></th>` or something? I do not do angular

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[innerHTML]=jsonObj.columName` and pass your data

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround or maybe the only solution at the moment:

The column that needs to contain the HTML now instead contains the index of the row.

I save these indices into an object that I loop through once the table is built.

I use `cell = document.evaluate` to get the HTML element using the xpath `//*[text() = " + index + "]`

I replace the innerHTML with the HTML string I need. `cell.innerHTML = '<p style="bold">cell data</p>'`

It works for what I need to do.